# Code either overloads memory or wont compile VBA

Tags: vba, excel, large-data

Trying to write a macro to insert a hyphen at specific points in a text string depending on how long the string is or delete all text after said point.

i.e 
- if 6 characters, insert a hyphen between char 4+5 or delete all text after char 4
- if 7 characters, insert a hyphen between char 5+6 or delete all text after char 5

Ideally i would love to be able to truncate the string at that point rather than hyphenate the text but i couldn't get my head around how to make it work so i decided to hyphen and then just run a find and replace '-*' to remove the unwanted characters. Can get this working on small sample sets 100-300 cells but i need the code to be able to go through workbooks with 70,000+ cells. I've tried tweaking the code to stop the memory issue but now i can't seem to get it to work.

```
Sub Postcodesplitter()
Dim b As Range, w As Long, c As Range, x As Long, d As Range, y As Long

For Each b In Selection
w = Len(b)
If w = 8 And InStr(b, "-") = 0 Then b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(b, 15 - w, 0, "-")

For Each c In Selection
x = Len(c)
If x = 7 And InStr(c, "-") = 0 Then c = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(c, 13 - x, 0, "-")

For Each d In Selection
y = Len(d)
If y = 6 And InStr(d, "-") = 0 Then d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(d, 11 - y, 0, "-")

Next
Next
Next
End Sub
```

That's the original code i put together, but it caused memory issues over 300 target cells. I'm a pretty bad coder even at the best of times but with some advice from a friend i tried this instead.

```
Sub Postcodesplitter()
Dim b As Range, x As Long

If (Len(x) = 6) Then
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(b, 11 - x, 0, "-")
Else
If (Len(x) = 7) Then
b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(b, 13 - x, 0, "-")
Else
If (Len(x) = 8) Then b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Replace(b, 15 - x, 0, "-")

End Sub
```

But this just throws out errors when compiling. I feel like im missing something really simple.

Any tips?

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: 'Block If without End If'.

If i put one 'End If' in, i get the same error.

If i put 2, i get no error but the code produces no results when it runs.

If i put 3, 'End If without Block If'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you want to truncate to two less than the existing number of characters, if that number is 6-8? If so, something like this:

```
Sub Postcodesplitter()
Dim data
Dim x as Long
Dim y as Long

data = Selection.Value
For x = 1 to ubound(data,1)
for y = 1 to ubound(data, 2)
Select Case Len(data(x, y))
Case 6 to 8
data(x, y) = left(data(x, y), len(data(x, y)) - 2)
end select
next y
next x
selection.value = data

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice usage of arrays (+1)

Comment: Is there a way to make this then count the instances of each string in the same run of code without then having to put everything into a pivot table?

So the goal is, to truncate a postcode down to 2 less than the number of existing characters, and then count how many of each postcode occur in the data.

e.g AB2 3CD becomes AB2 3 and then the macro tallies how many AB2 3's occur in the data? 12x AB2 3, 6x AB2 4, 1x AB3 7 etc.